# Giant alien robots controlled by dinosaurs

Tags: story-identification, movie

I'm looking for a movie I watched in early 2000s, but I'm not sure when it was filmed, maybe in the 80s.

It was about aliens having invaded Earth using giant robots. The rebels build their own robot from parts found in a car dump.

The main twist was that the aliens were in fact dinosaur like creatures. I think it was Indonesian (clearly Asian).

Maybe someone remembers this gorgeous trash.

Comment: Animated or live action?

Comment: It was live action. no CGI at all as far as I remember.